# How to check whether a file is open anywhere in a cluster using GFS and lvm?

Tags: linux, locking, cluster-computing, lvm, gfs

I wonder if it is possible to check if a file has already been opened by another node in the same GFS cluster. For example, the fuser command runs cluster-wide in TruCluster. Is it possible to query the lock manager's data via a command or API?